# How to change color of text when entering fixed div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a background color that is fixed in the browser.

Scrolling through the site, I want the text color to change from black to white when it meets this overlay, then back to black again as it leaves it. This isn't really possible in css yet, so how can I set this in jQuery?

I'm using the ScrollTo plugin (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) for my scrolling.

fiddle (css and html):
http://jsfiddle.net/L76NP/

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section">Section 1</div>
    <div class="section">Section 2</div>
    <div class="section">Section 3</div>
    <div class="section">Section 4</div>
    </div>

    <div id="overlay"></div></body>
```

css:

```
body {color: #000000}

#wrapper { margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto}

.section {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;}

#redbox {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -100;}
```

Comment: This would be extremely difficult. Your `<div class="section">` are 300px tall... so even if you coded it to detect when the section enters/leaves the overlay area; when you change its css `color:#fff` it would effect the entire 300px div -even parts that have not entered behind the red box overlay. Not possible to have a css style only effect _part_ of a div

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there another way jQuery could be used to affect all content within a certain portion of the screen?

Comment: No not really. Then you get into issues of when a single line of text is halfway on the overlay and halfway off the overlay. I single line can't be both #000 and #fff.

Comment: I see. Could it be possible if all text was converted to SVG images?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/ALcm6/3/

Basically checking if the section fits within the box, and if so it's changing the text color. You can alter this for your specific needs.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var redbox = $("#redbox");
    var redBoxTop = redbox.position().top;
    var redBoxBottom = redBoxTop + redbox.outerHeight();
    $(".section").each(function () {
        var section = $(this);
        var sectionTop = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + 15;
        var sectionBottom = section.position().top - $(window).scrollTop() + section.height();
        if ((sectionTop >= redBoxTop && sectionTop <= redBoxBottom) || (sectionTop <= redBoxTop && sectionBottom >= redBoxBottom) || (sectionBottom >= redBoxTop && sectionBottom <= redBoxBottom)) {
            section.css("color", "white");
        } else {
            section.css("color", "black");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: yes, it's clunky, but maybe I can make something like this work.

Comment: @zgood of course, I should have checked that! I updated the fiddle to check wither the top or bottom is within the red box or the top or bottoms are both outside of the redbox. Seems to work correctly now. Of course section 3 never goes back to black when exiting because the height of the element is more than the text and is still within the red box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#redbox').css('background-color','rgb(255,255,255)');//it's css controller
```

this is scroll event:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     $('#redbox').css('background-color','rgb(255,255,255)'); 
   } else {
     $('#redbox').css('background-color','rgb(0,0,0)');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQ9QP/

it's a sample code And You can customize it.

Comment: I think he wants to change the css text color of the `<div class="section">` as it gets scrolled under the red box overlay

Comment: Yes! for do it i lost very time And i programming now And i haven't enough time for do it...